# Can't get HTML5 Video id in HTML4 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

i need to track that a video is viewed or not, so i have found a trick that using javascript as follows

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('fce_video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }
        // What you want to do after the event
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

But my HTML version is 4, while i get video tag id it cause

```
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

what is wrong with my script?

Comment: HTML4 doesn't have a video tag, that would be HTML5

Comment: Nope, it is working in HTML4

Comment: Why do you think you're using HTML4? Are you actually testing on a browser published before 2009 (e.g., IE8, Firefox 3.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a html `video` tag in HTML4, it won't matter what you do, since that tag didnt exist in HTML4, hence why you're javascript can't find the tag.  If you're using a flash video, make sure to run your script after the page has loaded, it might be running before the video was rendered to the page.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can't find the element with `id="fce_video"`.

Make sure you run this script *after* the element has been included on the page.

Sometimes I see this:

```
[script here]
[referenced element here]
```

That doesn't work, you have to change the order.